# Force recreation of Heroku slug on git push

Tags: django, heroku, pip, slug, requirements.txt

I'm hosting a Django app on Heroku for a while already, and so far it worked fine. I now made some changes in the requirements.txt file, but feel like they are not correctly installed on Heroku when I make the git push. The log output shows the installation of some of the requirements, but not all of them. I guess the slug does not get recreated, but rather just updated. Is there a way to force the recreation of the complete slug?

Comment: officially, you'd open a support ticket. but see https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-repo, heroku repo:purge_cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-repo will allow you to do that. Just install and run `heroku repo:rebuild -a appname`

Comment: Hate to repeat myself (I already commented on another question), but I feel the need to warn people: After trying the heroku-repo plugin, I do *not* recommend it. There is a bad bug: it ignores the --app flag. This caused me to accidentally rebuild our production environment, when I meant to rebuild staging. This bug has been open against the repo for well over a year now with no resolution. I have uninstalled this plugin.